# Is directly accessing the backing array of a String justified in some cases?

Tags: java, arrays, string, reflection

I'm working on optimizing text processing software, in which the following class is used a lot:

```
class Sentence {

  private final char[] textArray;
  private final String textString; 

  public Sentence(String text) {
     this.textArray = text.toCharArray();
     this.textString = text;
  }

  public String getString() {
     return textString;
  }

  public char[] getArray() {
     return textArray;
  } 
}
```

As you can see, there is some redundancy: the backing array of the textString is always equal to the textArray, yet both are stored.

I'm hoping to reduce the memory footprint of this class, by getting rid of the textArray field.

There is one problem : this class is used widely througout out codebase, thus I cannot get rid of getArray() method. My solution is to get rid of the textArray field, and let the
getArray() method return the textSting's backing array instead via reflection.

The result would be something like:

```
class Sentence {

  private final String textString; 

  public Sentence(String text) {
       this.textString = text;
  }

  public String getString() {
     return textString;
  }

  public char[] getArray() {
     return getBackingArrayUsingReflection(textString);
  } 
}
```

It seems like a viable solution, but I suspect a String's backing array is private for a reason. What are potential problems with this approach?

Comment: Why not return the textString.toCharArray()?

Comment: Because textString.toCharArray() creates a new array each time it is called, and it is called very often.

Comment: Maybe you can refactor your code to use your own implementation of [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) instead of using reflection on `String`.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that will happen is that you are committing yourself to one specific implementation of the JDK. For example, Java 7 Update 6 has totally revamped its use of the `char[]`. This is why such an approach should be tolerated only if your code is very ephemeral, basically throw-away code.

If you are only reading the `char[]`, and you are coding for OpenJDK Java 7, Update 6, you won't introduce any bugs.

On the other hand, 95% of Java programmers around the world would probably shake their heads in disbelief at code that reflects upon `String` internals, so be careful :)

Comment: Actually, you will introduce bugs, see my answer.

Comment: +1 Some versions of Java 6 will use a `byte[]` were possible to save memory e.g. `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As I pointed out, he won't introduce bugs into one specific JDK implementation, which is Java 7 Update 6.

Comment: Wow, a downvote. I won't even ask for explanation because there can't be any. Downvoter, had a bad day?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of `java.lang.String` (Java 7 Update 5 and earlier), it uses a backing array, and the begin index and length (`count`) of the actual string in that array. In these implementations of Java the backing array can be (substantially) longer than the actual string and the string does not necessarily start at the start of the array.

For example when you use `substring`, the backing array could be identical to the backing array of the original String, but just with different start index and character count. So using reflection to return the backing array of the `String` doesn't work in all cases (or: it will result in incorrect/unexpected behavior).

See for example http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html `String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` on line 1950 (and below), which calls the constructor `String(int offset, int count, char value[])` on line 645 (and below). Here the `char[]` is directly used as the backing array, and offset and count are used as the offset into the array and the length of the string:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
        new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}

// Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
    this.value = value;
    this.offset = offset;
    this.count = count;
}
```

As indicated by Marko Topolnik, this is no longer the case with more [recent versions of Java 7](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html). You should not depend on the implementation details of Java (especially as it can change substantially between versions - as demonstrated).

Comment: Not true with the latest Java 7. See [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/) for proof.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik For reference, [this is what really happened](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html).

Comment: @assylias Great digging! Bookmarking that one for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you what it to be faster, use `String.charAt(i)` which will be inlined and avoids any issues with changes to inetrnals.  You can use the CharSequence if you want to avoid creating String from a StringBuilder as they both support this interface.

Comment: I would prefer charAt(i) as well, but there is lots of legacy code that uses the character arrays, so my Sentence class must expose a character array somehow.

Comment: If you access most frequently a char[], you could store `char[] textArray`, instantiating a new String when needed.

Comment: good point, but I access the strings and char[] with a roughly equal frequency

Answer (score 1):

For fun and games, run the following unit test:

```
public class StringTest {
    private String text;

    public StringTest() {
        super();
    }

    public char[] getBackingArray() {
        if (text == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            final Field valueField = text.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
            valueField.setAccessible(true);
            final char[] data = (char[]) valueField.get(text);
            return data;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Test
    public void testStringFunManipulation() {
        final StringTest test = new StringTest();
        test.setText("Hello World");
        Assert.assertNotNull(test);
        System.out.println("Original String: " + test);
        System.out
                .println("Original String Hash: " + test.getText().hashCode());

        char[] data = test.getBackingArray();
        Assert.assertNotNull(data);
        System.out.println("Backing Array: " + data);

        data[0] = 'J';
        System.out.println("Modified String: " + test);
        System.out
                .println("Modified String Hash: " + test.getText().hashCode());
        System.out.println("Modified String Hash Should be: "
                + "Jello World".hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text != null ? text.toString() : "";
    }
}
```

It should give you an answer on why exposing the internal, private values of classes ***can*** be a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, changing the backing array of a String directly this causes the hashCode to go out of sync with the value. Fortunately, I only need to read from the array, and never write to it.

Comment: @SynthC - once exposed, you really will lose control of how this array is used. How memory constrained is your application?

Comment: Memory is actually not the biggest problem: the applications is distributed, so network throughput is a bigger concern. I was hoping to achieve smaller sizes of serialized Sentences by exposing the backing array. It seemed like a simple solution, but is probably not worth  the potential bugs, I'll focus on optimizing the serialization procedure instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `getArray` implementation as follows:

```
public char[] getArray() 
{
    return this.textString.toCharArray();
}
```

Comment: I suspect that would be slower if it is called more than once.

Comment: yes agree. but looks more readable and easy to understand to me.

Comment: Do you realize that his first version of code does just that, but better?