# How to test the backing array used in Java Sting?

Tags: java, android, string, arrays, java-memory-model

While i was developing my Android application, my attention was caught by the [backing array](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#backing_array).

> Multiple strings can share the same char[] because strings are immutable. The substring(int) method always returns a string that shares the **backing array** of its source string. Generally this is an optimization: fewer character arrays need to be allocated, and less copying is necessary. But this can also lead to unwanted heap retention. Taking a short substring of long string means that the long shared char[] won't be garbage until both strings are garbage. This typically happens when parsing small substrings out of a large input. To avoid this where necessary, call new String(longString.subString(...)). The string copy constructor always ensures that the **backing array** is no larger than necessary.

Then i have read many resources on the web. I know that [Strings no longer shares the same backing array since jdk7u6](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html), pointed by [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934494/is-directly-accessing-the-backing-array-of-a-string-justified-in-some-cases).

Then i started trying to play with, and to test the existence of the shared backing array in my code:

```
String str = "1234567890";
System.out.println("str.substring(1): "    + (str == str.substring(1)));
System.out.println("str.substring(0, 9): " + (str == str.substring(0, 9)));
```

First i assume == is a swallow equal comparison (*isn't it?*) that compares their memory locations (like what in C).

If they **do** share the same backing array, and == is just comparing their memory locations, both statements **should** return true (*or* at least the last one returns true).

However, they are both false.

Well, i *think* my laptop is having Java 7 update 21. (shown in Win7 -> Control Panel -> Java Control Panel -> About) (and also in Eclipse -> Window -> Preference -> Java -> Compiler -> Compiler compliance level: {1.3 , 1.4 , 1.5 , 1.6 , 1.7} )

And i know 1.7 means Java 7. And i know Java 7 is too high that the shared backing array may already have taken away. That is why i have asked Eclipse to compile my project with 1.5 and 1.6.

```
Java project -> Properties -> Java Complier -> Compiler compliance level = 1.5
```

However, as i said, i am still getting false in those println()s.

Let me summarise my questions:

Q1) How to use Java codes to verify there is a use of underlying backing array? (other than making the OutOfMemoryError by millions of substring()s)

Q1) a. Is == sallow equal comparison?

Q1) b. Am i really using Java 5/6 to compile, if i set Compiler compliance level = 1.5/1.6?

Thanks for any input :-)

Comment: If there's any way short of reflection to determine the backing array of a `String`, that's probably a bug.

Comment: i dont really know what "reflection" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String objects will compare different even if they share the same backing char array, because the String objects themselves are different objects.

You can get the backing array using reflection. On my system the name of the backing array is `value` but there is no guarantee that it will be the same on yours.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Main
{
    static Field stringBackingField = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String strA = "1234567890";
        String strB = "1234567890";
        char[] charA = getBackingArray(strA);
        char[] charB = getBackingArray(strB);
        char[] subA1 = getBackingArray(strA.substring(1));
        char[] subA2 = getBackingArray(strA.substring(0, 9));
        System.out.println("charA address: " + System.identityHashCode(charA));
        System.out.println("charB address: " + System.identityHashCode(charB));
        System.out.println("subA1 address: " + System.identityHashCode(subA1));
        System.out.println("subA2 address: " + System.identityHashCode(subA2));
        System.out.println("charA == charB: " + (charA == charB));
        System.out.println("charA == subA1: " + (charA == subA1));
        System.out.println("charA == subA2: " + (charA == subA2));
    }

    public static char[] getBackingArray(String s) throws Exception
    {
        if (stringBackingField == null)
        {
            stringBackingField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
            stringBackingField.setAccessible(true);
        }
        return (char[]) stringBackingField.get(s);
    }
}
```

Output on Java 6:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java Main 
charA address: 1383884648
charB address: 1383884648
subA1 address: 1383884648
subA2 address: 1383884648
charA == charB: true
charA == subA1: true
charA == subA2: true
```

Output on Java 7:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java Main
charA address: 1264720121
charB address: 1264720121
subA1 address: 357935641
subA2 address: 722623040
charA == charB: true
charA == subA1: false
charA == subA2: false
```

---

**Edit:**

To find the name of the backing array member print all the members using

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(String.class.getDeclaredFields());
```

and look for one with type `char[]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And sorry for my erroneous println()s, because i am using Log.x(...) in my code in fact. Hmm.... seems the magic word `value` doesn't work for me. Is there a way to find out mine?

Comment: And also... in your output, does it mean returns from `substring()` does not share the same backing array? If it does, the last two statements would be true, isn't it? In addition, `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)` `Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode, sharing)` in my Win7 command prompt. Is it really possible to let my Eclipse to compile with an older version of Java? i doubt..

Comment: @midnite To change JRE in Eclipse: `Run > Run Configurations... > JRE > Alternate JRE`, and use `System.getProperty("java.version")` to check that it worked.

Comment: @midnite Yes, the results show that in Java 7 `substring()` returns a String which does not share the backing array.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. But [`java.version (Not useful on Android)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) :(

Comment: @midnite Sorry, didn't know about that. It appears the Android platform's runtime is completely independent of the JRE. Since the behaviour of `substring()` depends on the API version, not the compiler, doesn't that make the JRE 6/7 issue irrelevant?

Comment: My apology to @tom (& others), firstly, for this very very long delayed reply (i have been busying on other things). And, more importantly, @tom codes in fact WORKS LIKE A CHARM even on Android! The word `value` does do the magic. i thought it didnt because i messed up with `char[]` vs `String`, `Object.toString()` vs `String.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

substring() returns a new String object. Even if this returned new String would reference the same backing array, the String itself is a different object from the String calling the substring() method. Hence, when you use operator ==, it will return false.

```
class MyClass {
    public Object myObject;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Object sharedObject = new Object();

        MyClass sampleA = new MyClass();
        sampleA.myObject = sharedObject;

        MyClass sampleB = new MyClass();
        sampleB.myObject = sharedObject;


        //Same object shared by different objects. Returns true.
        System.out.println(sampleA.sharedObject == sampleB.sharedObject);

        //They are different objects, as it is your str and str.substring(1).
        //So this will return false.
        System.out.println(sampleA == sampleB);
    }
}
```

Comment: i understand what you mean. But how can we explain `String s1 = "123";` `String s2 = "12" + "3";` and `s1 == s2` is `true`?

Comment: @midnite Both strings are constant expressions so they are interned and share the same object. The second string is a constant expression because it is the concatenation of two constant expressions (see the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)). If you stored the parts in variables, e.g. `String a = "12"; String b = "3"; String s2 = a + b;` the second string would not be a constant expression; the concatenation will create a new String object and the comparison would return false.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't understand why you need to find this out. Since strings are immutable, as soon as you do an operation on it a new string is created (thus not affecting anything with the same "backing array"). As Louis said, it's not intended that you look this closely at the underlying works of strings from your code. There is not much point.

2) == compares the pointers of the 2 objects.

3) It is correct that those statements are false, since when you do the substring method it is creating a new string, therefore will have a different pointer to the original string.

Comment: For (1): it is because if substring() _does_ share the same backing array, i will use `new String(substring(...))` to prevent out of memory. Otherwise, i won't do so to save to process of creating the same string _again_.